# How to display a variable from a typescript file to a html file using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function in a typescript file:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    if (sessionStorage['loyalPage']) {
      this.page = Number(sessionStorage['loyalPage']);
    }

    this.webService.getLoyalPlayers(this.page).subscribe((player_vars:any)=>{
      this.player_list=player_vars;

      for (let i=0; i< this.player_list.length; i++) {
        let clubJoined: Date = new Date(this.player_list[i].club_joined);
        let todayDate: Date = new Date();

        var clubJoinedYear = clubJoined.getUTCFullYear();
        var currentYear = todayDate.getUTCFullYear();

        var years_at_club = currentYear - clubJoinedYear;
      }
   })
}
```

- `player_list` : array that holds players returned from mongoDB
- `clubJoinedYear` : holds year only from the date the player joined current club
- `currentYear` : holds current year
- `years_at_club` : works out how many years a player has been as a club

I want this `years_at_club` (int) var to be displayed in my HTML file and I am currently trying it like:

```html
<div class="p-year">
    {{ years_at_club }}
</div>
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR

src/app/loyal.component.html:71:24 - error TS2339: Property 'years_at_club' does not exist on type 'LoyalComponent'.

    {{ years_at_club }}
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/loyal.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './loyal.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoyalComponent.
```

[image]

How can I get this to print on my HTML file?

Comment: Deleted my answer since I didn't notice the looping going on, where's your `*ngFor` array coming from? You'll need to add the values there so you get the value of each iteration. Because currently you're just re-assigning the value to the same internal var of the loop on each one. Also don't forget to unsubscribe observables to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @ChrisW. This is the next issue I ran into, so the `*ngFor` iterates around each item in the player_list array, so I need the `years_at_club` for each player but how do I do that?

Comment: `years_at_club` is a var defined inside of a for-loop in your component ts. It doesn't exist outside of that for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access to a variable from the HTML-file, you must declare a `public` variable in the associated typescript file like

```
public years_at_club: number;
```

The `var` is only for variable on a component, as example in a method. This `var`-variable refers to the component instance and can‘t access from the associated HTML-file.

For the case in your `for`-loop, you can add every `years_at_club` where coming from MongoDB to a array, that looks like `public years_at_club_array: number[]` where you can add new items with `this.years_at_club_array.push(currentYear - clubJoinedYear)`.

In the HTML-file, you can display the array with looping over with `*ngFor`.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of years_at_club_array">
    <p>item</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
years_at_club:number;

ngOnInit() {
    if (sessionStorage['loyalPage']) {
      this.page = Number(sessionStorage['loyalPage']);
    }

    this.webService.getLoyalPlayers(this.page).subscribe((player_vars:any)=>{
      this.player_list=player_vars;

      for (let i=0; i< this.player_list.length; i++) {
        let clubJoined: Date = new Date(this.player_list[i].club_joined);
        let todayDate: Date = new Date();

        var clubJoinedYear = clubJoined.getUTCFullYear();
        var currentYear = todayDate.getUTCFullYear();

        this.years_at_club = currentYear - clubJoinedYear;
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: And how do you handle the `for`-loop? In your case, only the *last* item in the `player_list` would be stored in `this.years_at_club`. Is this the goal? I don‘t think…